# In MySQL, is it possible to get more than 1024 characters back from GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

I have a query which returns the count of a status that needs some very complex work to calculate. The user wants to drill down into that list, and I thought the easiest way would be to get the ids using GROUP_CONCAT.

Unfortunately, the result from GROUP_CONCAT is being truncated to 1024 (?!) characters.

Is it possible to get more than 1024 characters, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You need to set [`group_concat_max_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) to a higher value. This can be done on a session or global level. The following query sets the max length to 10,000 for the rest of the queries in that session:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000;
```

What you're running into is the [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) default max of 1024.

Comment: Hah, so simple when you know the details. You're an absolute star, and so quick!

Comment: I tried the similar thing but when i execute the query on mysql gui i can see the complete string but when i make a connection from nodejs and call the query the data is stripped off to 1024 characters only