# Query to fetch 1 row in table, and many rows from another table, referenced in that row

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database, left-join, inner-join

So I have 2 tables in my database, they are 'workouts' and 'exercises'. Workouts contains a row called exercises which is a comma-separated list of exercise IDs - from the 'exercises' table e.g. '1,2,3'.

My question is, can I write a single query to allow me to select a row from the workouts table, say one with an id of 1, and have MySQL fetch each of the exercises from the list in that row, returning them within the 'workout' row?

At the moment I'm using PHP to select the workout row, and then making individual requests for each of the exercises, resulting in serious inefficiency.

I took a look at [Joining rows as array from another table for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232274/joining-rows-as-array-from-another-table-for-each-row) and also did some research into the group_concat() function, but I'm not sure that's what I'm after.

**Update**
Here are the 2 tables:
[image]

Comment: Redesign your schema to have a cross-reference table called `exercises_workouts` (or something similar). Ditch the CSV field. It's going against the grain of what a database is supposed to help you solve.

Comment: So have a table that just has the fields 'workoutid' and 'exerciseid' and go from there?

Comment: Yes. http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/many-to-many.html

Comment: Right, that makes sense, if you post that as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, the best approach is to redesign your schema to have a cross-reference table called `exercises_workouts` (or something similar). Remove the CSV field.

Here's page that goes into more detail on implementing a many-to-many relationship:

http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/many-to-many.html

Note: The linked page uses the mysql_* functions, but the general explanation of the approach stands. You'll want to look into [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for database access.

Comment: Just drawn out the ERD for my database and it kinda shows how stupid my previous solution was :)