# Declare the size of a variable in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have below query which initializes @commid1 variable as **VARCHAR** but I would like to append more data to this variable So I need it to be **LONGTEXT**.

```
SELECT Ar.Communication_ids into @commid1 FROM 
View1 AR
AR Where LEN(Ar.Communication_ids) > 0 and ar.id =234 ;
```

How to make @commid1 = Longtext Type?
Or I will be converting it to procedures only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In MySQL, is it possible to get more than 1024 characters back from GROUP\_CONCAT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278184/in-mysql-is-it-possible-to-get-more-than-1024-characters-back-from-group-concat)

Comment: no it does not pertain to group_concat

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem.

Comment: The maximum length of a uservariable is only limited by the system variable `max_allowed_packet` (in bytes, so in case of e.g. utf-8, the length in characters can be 1/3 of that), and it will automatically use it, you don't have to specify that it is longtext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum length of a uservariable is only limited by the system variable max_allowed_packet (in bytes, so in case of e.g. utf-8, the length in characters can be 1/3 of that), and it will automatically use it, you don't have to specify that it is longtext.