# Correct way to concatenate string within GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: html, mysql

I know this must be pretty basic, but I'm trying to make a query where I can show a continent and then show all countries with airport from that continent, so far, this query works for me:

```
$sql = "SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ,country, SEPARATOR '')
      as country
      FROM airports
      GROUP BY continent
      ORDER BY continent, country ASC";
      if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
          if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                  echo "<hr>" . $row['continent'] . "" . $row['country'] . "";
              }

              // Free result set
              mysqli_free_result($result);
          } else{
              echo '<div class="autocomplete__item alert--warning"> No records matching your query were found.</div>';
          }
      } else{
          echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
      }
```

It shows the continent name, and every country in it with one or more airports. So, I need that Country output to be surrounded by a lot of HTML. I guess the best way is to nest queries, but, I've done it in the same GROUP_CONCAT declaration and it works! Except for the fact that the HTML breaks.

I change GROUP_CONCAT to:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT '<div class=\"push-button\"><input type=\"checkbox\"  id=\"',alpha_2,'\"><label for=\"',alpha_2,'\">',country,'</label></div>' SEPARATOR '')
```

That technically works, but it breaks the markup at some point:

```
<div class="push-button">
     <input type="checkbox"  id="bm">
     <label <hr>Asia<div class="push-button"><input type="checkbox"  id="cn"><label for="cn">China</label></div>
```

Or another the last row:

```
<div class="p    </section>
```

That happens some 5 or 6 times in 56 countries.

Probably I should nest queries, not sure and not sure how to do it, but... Isn't this weird or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000;
```

Ok, Solved. The problem wasn't GROUP_CONCAT braking the markup, it happens that it has a max value, by default 1024 (I found out making test with MySQL Workbench).

So I found a solution here: [In MySQL, is it possible to get more than 1024 characters back from GROUP_CONCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278184/in-mysql-is-it-possible-to-get-more-than-1024-characters-back-from-group-concat)